# Is sqlite bundled into Django?

Tags: django, sqlite

Does Django come with sqlite bundled or is it a separate module?

Can't figure this out, even by looking at Django source:
https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/backends/sqlite3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
21  try:
22      try:
23          from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as Database
24      except ImportError, e1:
25          from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
26  except ImportError, exc:
27      from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
28      raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
```

It first attempts to import [PySqlite](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite), an external module. If that fails, it tries to import the sqlite3 module included in Python 2.5+. If neither Python 2.5+ nor the external module are installed, it fails. It does not include its own copy.

Answer (score 4):

Sqlite is part of the Python standard library, so it is always available to Django.

Answer (score 3):

I think SQLite comes standard with Python 2.5+ - so it doesn't need to be bundled with Django.